# How is throw statement inside catch block preventing compiler error for uninitialized variable?

Tags: java, exception

I am trying to figure out the inner workings of this code.

```
public void method() {
    int x;
    try {
        x = 10;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(); //commenting out this line causes error
    }
    System.out.println("x: " + x);
}
```

When I comment out line 6, I get a compilation error on line 8 that x might have not been initialized. When I keep the throw statement inside the catch block, I get no such error. How does this make any difference? The way I see it, you can either initialize a variable inside a try block and use that value outside, or you cannot. At any rate, no exceptions are actually thrown because the catch block is never entered. Surely the mere possibility of an exception being thrown isn't causing the compiler to allow what would otherwise be a violation of Java syntax, right?

Comment: What is the java version?

Comment: @NomadMaker Java 11

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- Nope, I only get the one error I mentioned. Unless I'm mistaken, this is just as much a compile-time error as putting in an extra bracket or forgetting a semicolon, so how can this be allowed?

Comment: Just duplicated this. I can't understand why it's happening yet.

Comment: I think I just figured it out.

Comment: @MadPhysicist It's been a long week.

Comment: @chrylis  I feel ya :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the simple code:

```
int x;
System.out.println(x);
```

The compiler detects that variable `x` may not have been initialized at the point where it is referenced, so it throws a compile error.
Now looking at your example, there are two paths the compiler can be sure about that code can take: Execute the try block or execute the catch block (with the latter, partial execution of the try block is possible as well). In this second case, the `x` variable will not be initialized and the compiler cannot generate sensible bytecode instructions. However, with the `throws` in the catch block, the execution of this code will stop and the usage of `x` is never reached, solving the uninitialized variable problem for the compiler.

To include another example that might be easier to understand:

```
int x;
if(someCondition()) {
    x = 1;
} else {
    // x is not initialized through this code path.
}
System.out.println(x); // x may be initialized here, but it is not guaranteed, so this causes a compile error.
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak to whether there are any real exceptions that could occur within the `try` – something like [`OutOfMemoryError`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html) *might* occur, but wouldn't be caught with `catch (Exception e)` – but I believe this is just due to the compiler being extra careful (perhaps unnecessarily so).

It isn't relevant that the line inside your `try` block doesn't throw an exception. Instead, it's evaluating that if an exception were to be thrown inside the `try` statement (somehow) and execution was subsequently allowed to continue past the `catch` clause, then `x` would be in an uninitialized state.

The exact answer is most likely buried in the Java Language Spec, possibly in [14.21. Unreachable Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21) or [14.20.1. Execution of try-catch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.1).

Comment: InterruptedException. MemoryError is unlikely to be a possibility for a primitive allocated on the stack. Although StackOverflowError could I suppose.

Comment: `InterruptedException` could fit. I agree that `OutOfMemoryError` isn't likely - I changed the wording above from "could occur" to "_might_ occur". Indeed there are probably very few scenarios in which the single line `x = 10` would result in an exception of any kind.

Comment: The issue with a stack overflow in this context is that is an Error, which isn't an Exception.